# Update status bar tooltip in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am creating a GUI with status bar using PowerShell. Here is code:

```
 $StatusBar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.StatusBar
 $StatusBarPanel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.StatusBarPanel
 $StatusBarPanel.AutoSize = [System.Windows.Forms.StatusBarPanelAutoSize]::Contents
 $StatusBarPanel.text = "Ready.."
 $StatusBarPanel.ToolTipText = $StatusBarPanel.text
 $StatusBar.showpanels = $True 
 $StatusBar.Panels.Add($StatusBarPanel)
```

Initially, I am setting **Ready..** as tooltip content. Later I have to display some path in status bar which be calculated at runtime. Status bar shows correct path but tooltip doesn't get updated.

It keeps showing **Ready..**. Small code snippet is here:

```
$StatusBarPanel.text = "Hotfix successfully created at -" + $hotfixFolder    
$StatusBarPanel.ToolTiptext = $StatusBarPanel.text
```

Can anybody guide what am I missimg to update tooltip?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out exact problem but got a workaround. I stoted value is a temp variable and assigned same as mentioned here:

```
$StatusBarPanel.text = "Hotfix successfully created at -" + $hotfixFolder  
$temp = $StatusBarPanel.text   
$StatusBarPanel.ToolTiptext = $temp
```

I am not sure how this is working but it worked for me...